# CQ CRXDE lite servlet class location

Tags: aem, crx

Looking for the location of the servlet class of a compiled jsp. This is for debugging purpose.
Version: CQ 5.6.1. 
IDE: CRXDE Lite

Comment: Did you check `/var/classes/org/apache/jsp/apps/<<your_proj>>/components/`?

Comment: @rakhi4110 Thanks for the reply. Thats the path where the i found my servlet.